# mvc actionlink show html tags

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, tags, actionlink

how can i show html tags like this

```
html.actionlinlk("<b>bla bla</b>", null)
```

it dislay **bla bla** not bold bla bla-is it possible to show bold text?

Comment: Yey! i think maybe some user does not want to respond your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly agree with Darin Dimitrov. You should not store html in your db. But you can solve this problem anyway. Ether you use Url.Action and write the `<a />` tag your self. Like this:

```
<a href="<%=Url.Action("action", "controller")%>">Text</a>
```

Or you will have to build your own html extension for actionlink as the default one (correctly) html encodes the value you put in.

I would suggest the first one as I think you should write the html your self instead of using a helper. It's not hard to write a `<a />` tag.

Answer (score 0):

I think your looking for:

```
<b><%= Html.ActionLink("bla bla", null) %></b>
```

**Update**

Ah ok I see what you are looking for. Well the first parameter of the ActionLink extension method is the link text (of the anchor element). As far as I am aware it should support HTML tags.

e.g.

`<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">stack<b>overflow</b></a>` gives you [stack**overflow**](http://stackoverflow.com)

Comment: emmmm, <b> was only for example, i have different html tags , they comes from database

Answer (score 0):

Databases are for storing data. HTML is markup. Don't store HTML inside a database. As you've mixed data and markup you will now need to extract the data (`bla bla`) from the markup and formatting (`<b>`). There are tools allowing you to parse HTML such as  [HTML Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack). You could always try parsing it with a regular expression but as you may see [this is not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

So my suggestion is to modify your design and separate markup from real data.

Answer (score 0):

My solution about this problem was to create an extension method. You can read the (short) full story [here](http://h-e-m-m-e.blogspot.com/2010/06/avoiding-html-encoding-when-calling.html).